# Facebook URLs cannot be crawled

Tags: php, facebook

I have an application with an iframe to one of my websites.

I want to do the simplest posting via news.reads actions.

I get the next error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL http://fb.raal.co.il/ has og:type of 'website'. The property 'article' requires an object of og:type 'article'. thrown in /home1/raalcoil/public_html/fb/src/base_facebook.php on line 1106
```

after looking through a bit, I came accross these errors on the Debugger:

```
Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed

Facebook URL:   Facebook URLs cannot be crawled.
Errors That Must Be Fixed

Missing Required Property:  The 'og:url' property is required, but not present.
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

Link to the debugger:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffb.raal.co.il%2F

the website itself: http://fb.raal.co.il/

Why cant facebook crawl into my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why cant facebook crawl into my website?

Because you page automatically *redirects* to facebook.com – to be more precise, to the Auth dialog.

You can see that in the debugger output, under *Redirect Path*.

If you want your users to be automatically redirected to the Auth dialog (which I don’t like from a user perspective, because I’d like to see what a page/app has to offer first, before authorising it) – then do it for *users* only, i.e. exclude the Facebook scraper from that (by user agent or/and IP adresses).